How to check what is being sent?
How to check what is being sent with the SendAsync method?
How can I visualize in XML form what will be sent to the target server?
I am looking for the reason why the server rejects it.
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(this.soapXML);
// Usage (XDocument -> UTF-8 bytes)
ByteArrayContent content = doc.ToByteArrayContent();

NetworkCredential networkCredential =
    new NetworkCredential(this.userName, this.userPassword);

Uri uri = new Uri(this.endPointAddres);
CredentialCache credentialCache = new CredentialCache
{
    { uri, "Digest", networkCredential }
};

HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()
{
    Credentials = credentialCache,
    PreAuthenticate = true
});

HttpRequestMessage request = 
    new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);
request.Headers.Add("UsernameToken", userNameTokenId);
request.Headers.Add("Username", userName);
request.Headers.Add("Password", passwordDigest);
request.Headers.Add("Nonce", nonce);
request.Headers.Add("Created", createdStr);
request.Content = content;
MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaTypeHeaderValue = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/soap+xml");
request.Content.Headers.ContentType = mediaTypeHeaderValue;   

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

The server returns a message like this:

InternalServerError <soap:Envelope
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">soap:Bodysoap:Faultsoap:ServerCouldn't
parse stream.</soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>


You can just inspect the request object and the client (for DefaultHeaders and such). But my guess would be that it wants the correct Content-Type header, ie "application/soap+xml" or just "application/xml". Right now it is probably just "application/octet-stream" if sent at all.

I added to the code. Is that OK? If OK, it didn't help.
MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaTypeHeaderValue = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(“application/soap+xml”);
request.Content.Headers.ContentType = mediaTypeHeaderValue;

Yeah that is fine. Seems like there is something else wrong with your request then. Either the XML is actually wrong or the ToByteArrayContent extension method does something weird. I'm no SOAP expert so I can't tell if that error is for something specific (it can of course also be dependent on the soap server implementation).
